# cmake: how to force a project not to use cache?

Tags: caching, cmake

Projects generate a CMakeCache.txt file, and as a result the cmake instructions of the CMakeLists.txt will not run twice if the CMakeLists.txt is not changed.

I would like a specific project to not generate a CMakeCache.txt file (or alternatively, to ignore the one that has been generated). I would like this to be automated, i.e. not to have to delete the file manually.

Context: I am using [colcon](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/) to compile several projects, and I would like the cache to be ignored only for a specific package, no all.

(An alternative could be to be able to force the execution of a specific macro, independently of whether or not the CMakeLists.txt file has been changed or not.)

Comment: CMake itself and most project relies on the cache. It is impossible to disable it. As for not creating resulting file `CMakeCache.txt`, CMake unlikely provides such possibility: Without `CMakeCache.txt` the project will be completely reconfigured on next `cmake` run, which has a little sense from the configuration point of view.

Comment: what if something changed on the target machine?

Comment: "what if something changed on the target machine?" - If changing in that "something" is not detectable by CMake, then just drop the build directory and configure the project again. Some configuration tools (like Autotools) provides `distclean` target for clean the configuration. But since CMake encourages out-of-source builds, such "clean the configuration" purpose could be performed with simple `rm -r <build_dir>` and doesn't require support from CMake.

Comment: It's always possible to explicitly reconfigure the project running `cmake <build directory>`. If in addition to this you indeed do need to "ignore cache entries", you can pass the values to delete from the cache before running the reconfiguration, by adding one or more `-U <cache var>` as option to this call. E.g. to delete cache variables `FOO` and `BAR` for the reconfiguration of the build directory `baz`, you can use `cmake -U FOO -U BAR baz` There's also the command `unset(<variable> CACHE)` to achieve the same effect from your `CMakeLists.txt`...